# Does VWAP distinguish between buy and sell trading volume?

Tags: vwap

VWAP is a ratio of the cumulative value (price ($p$) times volume ($q$)) traded in a stock, divided by total traded volume during the day:

$$\frac{\sum{q \times p}}{\sum{q}}$$

Does the volume component ($q$) that appears in the numerator and denominator distinguish between buy and sell trades somehow? (negative $q$ for sell, and positive $q$ for buy.) Or does it treat both long and short as positive values?

Answer (score 2):

The first reference I can find on Google Scholar is "The Total Cost of Transactions on NYSE" by Stephan A. Berkowitz, Dennis E. Logue and Eugene A. Noser, Jr. in the Journal of Finance. Their definition on page 4 (100 in the journal) doesn't consider the side of the trade.

Of course, this doesn't prevent anyone from defining a different measure that does include this information but it would not quite be VWAP.

Comment: do u have suggestions on how volume data can be used to infer net buy or sell activity over the course of a day, with or without the VWAP? what would be a more appropriate metric when  data on trade size, but not trade *side*, is not given (i.e. non-intraday data)?

Comment: No, I don't see a way to go from VWAP to trade side. You could try to make a model that combines the VWAP with OHLC data to get an idea of trade side (I think mainly on shorter time intervals this could give reasonable results) but to make such a model you would need historic trade side data as well.